# Inserting zero-width space after each symbol

Tags: excel, vba, zero-width-space

I need to place a zero-width space after each character within the texts in MS Excel document.
Two important conditions:

- The target text is in Japanese and Chinese.
- Text with Latin characters and numbers should not be affected. I.e. in mixed Asian\Latin cell only Asian characters have to be separated by those spaces.

Amount of texts is huge so it's a pain to put them in manually.

I tried to find any suitable VBA-module out, but with no success.

Maybe it's possible to perform such action in another application and then import the texts back to Excel? That's solution is also acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Exceptions (Latin characters):

> 65
>   66
>   67
>   68
>   69
>   70
>   71
>   72
>   73
>   74
>   75
>   76
>   77
>   78
>   79
>   80
>   81
>   82
>   83
>   84
>   85
>   86
>   87
>   88
>   89
>   90
>   91
>   92
>   93
>   94
>   95
>   96
>   97
>   98
>   99
>   100
>   101
>   102
>   103
>   104
>   105
>   106
>   107
>   108
>   109
>   110
>   111
>   112
>   113
>   114
>   115
>   116
>   117
>   118
>   119
>   120
>   121
>   122

Comment: Which uni-code character do you want to use??

Comment: This one, see here:
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm

Comment: ......................See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

***U+200B***

This little macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim zws As String, A1 As String, L As Long, i As Long
    Dim temp As String

    zws = ChrW(8203)
    A1 = Range("A1").Text

    L = Len(A1)
    For i = 1 To L
        temp = temp & Mid(A1, i, 1) & zws
    Next i

    temp = Mid(temp, 1, Len(temp) - 1)
    MsgBox A1 & vbCrLf & temp

    Range("A2").Value = temp
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

**NOTE:**

The character may be zero-width, but not zero-length!

Comment: Thanks for this macro! However, I've mentioned that Latin characters or numbers should not be affected. Is it any way to modify the macro and add exceptions there?

Comment: @JohnnyLeoni  **YES**  just update your original question with the uni-code IDs *(in decimal)* of the exceptions.